# for loop logic several values within an array - Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Having a problem. The below works great at populating a jquery datatable. The arrays dataX are short strings of arrays (each one like 7 elements). Seemed like a good way to do the table! and worked okay at the time.

My problem is I want to check the 4th element within each of the dataX arrays and if it's "fail" then precede the text with "Test". I've tried this a number of times but seem to have not succeeded. Is there an eloquent way of doing this check? Will I have to separate the for loop into two as it uses the index variable in two ways? I've tried using two variables instead of index twice, and feel i'm making headway, but can't sort the logic mentally.

```
 for (var index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
    //if (index != 4) {
        $(row1cells[index + 1]).html(data1[index]);
        $(row2cells[index + 1]).html(data2[index]);
        $(row3cells[index + 1]).html(data3[index]);
        $(row4cells[index + 1]).html(data4[index]);
        $(row5cells[index + 1]).html(data5[index]);
        $(row6cells[index + 1]).html(data6[index]);
        $(row7cells[index + 1]).html(data7[index]);
    }

 })
```

Comment: How is it working if the `if` is quoted?

Comment: What happen if you use `if (index != 4) {`? I think you need the same condition. or may be it should `if(index!=3) {` as your `index` started from `0`

Comment: what is `rowcells`??

Comment: Sorry, answering those queries. The If bit was one of my attempts (but it went on for like 50 LOC so I cut it out).

Sorry should have included eg for RowXcells:
var row1cells = $("#row1 td");

Taking a look at the solution below now : )..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood but try that:

```
var format = function(index, data) {
        var value = data[index];

        if (index === 4 && value === 'fail') {
            return 'Test' + value;
        }

        return value;
    }
;

for (var index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
    $(row1cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data1));
    $(row2cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data2));
    $(row3cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data3));
    $(row4cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data4));
    $(row5cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data5));
    $(row6cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data6));
    $(row7cells[index + 1]).html(format(index, data7));
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you don't need to nest another if to check if value is `'fail'` just use logical and in same if condition

Comment: You're totally right, didn't know why I coded it like that. Fixed and edited.

Comment: Thanks very much Gnucki, I accomplished something similar with 50 LOC... hahaha. Merry Christmas!